# Entity Framework Core subquery: Error System.InvalidOperationException : Nullable object must have a value in

Tags: c#, linq, exception, entity-framework-core

I have the following method in the entity framework (It has less properties for simplicity but the important thing is there):

```
public async Task<TemplateDetailsDto?> SearchDetailsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Guid templateKey)
{
    var search = await (from template in context.Set<Template>()
                        join ratingDef in context.Set<RangeDefinition>() on template.FinalRatingRangeId equals ratingDef.Id into ratingGroup
                        from ratingDef in ratingGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where template.Key == templateKey
                        select new TemplateDetailsDto
                        {
                            Key = template.Key,
                            FinalRatingRange = ratingDef == null ? null : (new TemplateRangeDetailsDto
                            {
                                Legend = ratingDef.Legend,
                                RangeTypeId = (QuestionsTypeDto)ratingDef.RangeTypeId,
                                RangesValues = context.Set<RangeValue>()
                                        .Where(rangValue => rangValue.RangeDefinitionId == ratingDef.Id)
                                        .Select(rangValue => new TemplateRangeDetailsDto
                                        {
                                            Id = rangValue.Id,
                                            Value = rangValue.Value,
                                        })
                                        .ToList(),
                            }),
                        })
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

    return search;
}
```

And I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Nullable object must have a value

on this line of code:

```
RangesValues = context.Set<RangeValue>()
    .Where(rangValue => rangValue.RangeDefinitionId == ratingDef.Id)
    .Select(rangValue => new TemplateRangeDetailsDto
    {
        Id = rangValue.Id,
        Value = rangValue.Value,
    })
    .ToList(),
```

If I comment on that part everything is working like a charm. The problem is that ratingDef can be null and the subquery gives me the error because ratingDef is null, so, how do you think I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I was testing using this (I'm testing using an in-memory database):

```
[Fact]
public async Task SearchDetailsAsync_WhenInvokeWithNullRating_ShouldGetData()
{
    //Arrange
    var context = CreateContext();
    var templateSearcher = await CreateTemplateSearcherAsync(context);
    var expectedTemplateId = 1;
    var templateToGet = await context.Set<Template>().Where(temp => temp.Id == expectedTemplateId).SingleAsync();

    //Act
    var result = await templateSearcher.SearchDetailsAsync(default, templateToGet.Key);

    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);

    ContextTestHelper.Dispose(templateSearcher);
}
```

And the call stack of the result of the test:

> Message: 
> System.InvalidOperationException : Nullable object must have a value.

**Stack Trace:**

```
lambda_method2119(Closure, ValueBuffer)
WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
lambda_method2091(Closure)
ResultEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
Enumerator.MoveNextHelper()
Enumerator.MoveNextAsync()
ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
TemplateSearcher.SearchDetailsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Guid templateKey) line 41
TemplateSearcherTests.SearchDetailsAsync_WhenInvokeWithNullRating_ShouldGetData() line 554
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

**Update 2:**
This is the SQL generated:

```
DECLARE @__ef_filter__TenantId_1 varchar(50) = 'xxxxxxxx';
DECLARE @__ef_filter__TenantId_2 varchar(50) = 'xxxxxxxx';
DECLARE @__ef_filter__TenantId_0 varchar(50) = 'xxxxxxxx';
DECLARE @__templateKey_0 uniqueIdentifier = 'some-guid-key';

SELECT [f].[Key], CASE
    WHEN [t].[Id] IS NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END, [t].[Legend], CAST([t].[RangeTypeId] AS tinyint), [f].[Id], [t].[Id], [t0].[Id], [t0].[Value]
FROM [template].[Templates] AS [f]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[Legend], [r].[RangeTypeId]
    FROM [template].[RangesDefinitions] AS [r]
    WHERE [r].[TenantId] = @__ef_filter__TenantId_1
) AS [t] ON [f].[FinalRatingRangeId] = [t].[Id]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [r0].[Id], [r0].[Text], [r0].[RangeDefinitionId]
    FROM [template].[RangesValues] AS [r0]
    WHERE [r0].[TenantId] = @__ef_filter__TenantId_2
) AS [t0] ON [t].[Id] = [t0].[RangeDefinitionId]
WHERE [f].[TenantId] = @__ef_filter__TenantId_0 AND [f].[Key] = @__templateKey_0
ORDER BY [f].[Id], [t].[Id]
```

The funny thing is that the SQL execution runs smoothly, so maybe I have a problem with the mocks, or is it a db in-memory problem? checking....

Thank you Nikola for proposing to review the generated query! :D

**Update 3:**
I was doing tests and it only happens an error in the memory DB when it has some of the null data from the subquery. The rest of the SQL in-memory tests work fine, now the SQL database one works fine in any case so as they mentioned it is probably an issue of the DB in memory, I'm going to see how viable it is to switch to SqlLite In-Memory as they mentioned.

Thank you all so much for your help.

Comment: you have declare 'ratingDef ' more than 1, please check about that first...

Comment: First of all, don't join, use navigation properties.

Comment: Your query is odd. Looks like you're trying to do an outer join on the same table that's in your from statement. I doubt that's what you're attempting to do. It's failing because somewhere in that result set you're returning nullable records and ratingDef.Id is null. Add the EF logger prior to the query and read the generated sql in the output window.

Comment: Please show call stack.

Comment: Added stack trace!

If you tell me how I can change it or some example of how it could be, I can change it and try it.

Comment: Well, it can be bug in Memory Provider, which is fixed very rarely. Try SqlLite In-Memory instead.

Comment: Indeed, it's a well-known fact that you shouldn't use the in-memory provider for unit tests.

Comment: I'll try Sqlite In-Memory, but your comment caught my attention Gert Arnold, it seemed like a good way to test the queries, do you recommend using the real database directly? or what is your recommendation?

Comment: I can't recommend anything without knowing all details, but see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in update 3, it seems to be a problem with the in-memory DB.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

That part of code is probably executed in memory and not translated to sql.
You could check generated sql query in logs or by calling .ToQueryString() extension method and verify.

I had success resolving this kind of situations with LinqKit library.

Btw asNoTracking is not necessary here because result is projection and not tracked entity.